# Looping through an extensive file and use each column as input

Tags: bash, file, input

I want to run one software that takes three inputs. When I am running analysis on the cluster I can use Slurm to get each column as input for a job array.

```
samplesheet="test.txt"
name=`sed -n "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"p $samplesheet |  awk '{print $1}'`
foward=`sed -n "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"p $samplesheet |  awk '{print $2}'`
reverse=`sed -n "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"p $samplesheet |  awk '{print $3}'`
```

Then I can run the software with the command:

```
software --imput $foward $reverse --output $name
```

It works for a job array. I want to do something similar on my computer.
For example, I have a file:

```
sample001   file001a  file001b
.
.
.
sample1000  file1000a  file1000b
```

The first column will be the prefix of the output file and, columns 1 and 2 are two input files.

I have tried to use a loop or xargs, but it works for one column.
For example:

For example,

```
for line in test.txt
do
     # do something with $line here
done
```

or

```
cat test.txt | while read line 
do
   # do something with $line here
done
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If I'm understanding your requirement correctly, please try: `while read -r name forward reverse; do echo software --input "$forward" "$reverse" --output "$name"; done < test.txt`.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, you're best to use read inside of a while loop,  as such:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

line_num=0
while read line; do
    line_num=$((line_num + 1))
    part_1=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f1)
    part_2=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f2)
    part_3=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f3)
    echo "Line ${line_num} Part 1: ${part_1} Part 2: ${part_2} Part 3: ${part_3}"
done < <(cat ./sample.txt)
```

sample.txt:

```
sample001   file001a  file001b
sample002   file002a  file002b
sample003   file003a  file003b
sample004   file004a  file004b
sample005   file005a  file005b
sample006   file006a  file006b
sample007   file007a  file007b
sample008   file008a  file008b
sample009   file009a  file009b
sample010   file010a  file010b
```

Output:

```
$ ./read-from-file.sh 
Line 1 Part 1: sample001 Part 2: file001a Part 3: file001b
Line 2 Part 1: sample002 Part 2: file002a Part 3: file002b
Line 3 Part 1: sample003 Part 2: file003a Part 3: file003b
Line 4 Part 1: sample004 Part 2: file004a Part 3: file004b
Line 5 Part 1: sample005 Part 2: file005a Part 3: file005b
Line 6 Part 1: sample006 Part 2: file006a Part 3: file006b
Line 7 Part 1: sample007 Part 2: file007a Part 3: file007b
Line 8 Part 1: sample008 Part 2: file008a Part 3: file008b
Line 9 Part 1: sample009 Part 2: file009a Part 3: file009b
Line 10 Part 1: sample010 Part 2: file010a Part 3: file010b
```

Note: I assume that your file is space delineated, hence the cut command.  Also, the sample.txt does need a trailing newline for the cat command to work effectively in this case.

It could probably be prettied up a bit inside the while loop, but it is effective.